# Cufon - ignore child elements

Tags: javascript, html, tags, cufon

I have seen similar questions here, but none of them answer what the title says precisely. If I apply Cufon to a DIV element and it contains children of various tags, (span,div,ul) how can I make Cufon ignore all of those elements?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
Cufon.replace('div#id', {
    ignore: {
        span: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but that would only ignore specific tags and not all of the child elements simultaneously. Besides, If i have a DIV2 inside DIV1, and I want to apply Cufon to DIV1 but not DIV2, and I do it your way (Ignore {div: true}) both DIVs will be ignored.